# Fire multiple delays sequentially

Tags: python, twisted

My class should take the current start time, and activate the end time by delaying it with `clock` by calling the function later by the given delay amount. Then I want to fire another `clock` that delays a print function and embeds the value of the final end-time to it.

However, I cannot yet understand how to fire both sequentially, for example:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor

from twisted.internet.task import Clock
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
#import time

class controlTime:

    start_time = time.time()

    def end_time(self):
        end_time = time.time()
        print(end_time)
        #time.sleep(3)
        return end_time

    def delayTime(self, delay=0):
        clock = Clock()
        clock.callLater(delay, self.end_time)
        clock.advance(delay)

    def additionalFunc(self, sec):
        final_time = sec - self.start_time
        print(f'You have delayed for: {final_time} s')
    
    def  finalTime(self, g_delay=0):
        clock = Clock()
        clock.callLater(g_delay, self.additionalFunc, self.end_time())
        clock.advance(g_delay)

ctrl = controlTime()
#
#
deferred_signal = Deferred()
deferred_signal2 = Deferred()

dl1 = deferred_signal.addCallback(ctrl.delayTime)
dl1.callback(3)

dl2 = deferred_signal2.addCallback(ctrl.finalTime)
dl2.callback(3)
```

The issue is that no delay is activated and each function get's fired straight away.

`time.sleep` can help with the delay, however I want to avoid using this and rely on the built-in delays provided by clock.

Comment: This might be a good time for you to practice your debug skills. The following three references give excellent advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: @itprorh66 My guess is that `callback` does not send an input value to the parameter `delay` or `g_delay`, therefore it takes the fixed value of `0`. Therefore, there is a delay, however it's at the fixed value and not the given value in callback.

Comment: So what does the documentation for callback say? Or what does the code for the callback class look like?